# Clarifications regarding .NET config files

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config

I have a few questions regarding the app.config and web.config files in .NET projects.

1.If I have 1 main project referencing a side project, and each one has its own settings section, is there any way I can automatically copy the referenced project's settings to the main app.config?

2. If I delete the config file from the prod enviorment, my assembly will load the default vales it had during compilation time. Can I somehow override this behaviour?
3. Can I have multiple config files for the same projects, each for a different enviorement? Like a config file for Debug, and one for Release?

Answer (score 0):

1. Only one config file is loaded. If you need to use several config files coming from other projects, you need to load your configuration programmaticaly. This means that you can have a different config file per project, copy them in the final folder when building and load them with ConfigurationManager:

```cs
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "customConfigFile.xml";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile,     ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
```

You can load a section dedicated to a specific project:

```
config.GetSection("SomeSection")
```

2/3. For choosing between two files for debug and release, you can use the example above, and use for executing specific code in Debug:

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```